# POST request works in Postman but not in browser (500 internal error) in react/node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Im building the register page of my app and when I try to register a new user to send data to mongo atlas, I just cant (It appears 500 internal error, and dont say nothing more specific). The thing is it worked without problems just few hours ago with same code, and I can in Postman also.

I have this code in my react register page to make the POST request:

```
export default function RegisterPage(props) {
    const { register, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
    const refForm =  useRef(null);
    const [profImage, setProfImage] =  useState(null)

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const formData = new FormData(refForm.current);

        API.post('usuarios', formData, {
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('userID', res.data.usuario._id);
        })
    };
```

my API.js file:

```
export const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_URL,
    timeout: 6000,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
});
```

the route in /usuarios:

```
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);

    const nombreCompleto = req.body.nombreCompleto
    const foto = IMAGES_URL_BASE + "/" + req.file.filename
    const email = req.body.email
    const password = req.body.password
    const contact = req.body.contact
    

    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
        const usuario = new Usuarios()

        usuario.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
        usuario.foto = foto;
        usuario.email = email;
        usuario.password = hash;
        usuario.contact = contact;
        


        usuario.save()
            .then((newUsuario) => {
                const accessToken = jwt.sign(
                    { userID: newUsuario._id, nombreCompleto: newUsuario.nombreCompleto },
                    process.env.JWT_SECRET);
                return res.json({ logged: true, token: accessToken, usuario: newUsuario })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                res.status(500).send(error);
            })
    });
});
```

I appreaciate any help! thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to compare the exact requests (Headers, content, ...) from your browsers developer options and postman (if there are equal)? At best compare them in plain text.

Comment: An easy way to compare the two requests is to use postman and developer tools to convert each request to a curl command.